# How to debug apk file

Tags: android, debugging

I want to debug apk file(android).

However, target apk file is encrypted by specific apk protector.

So, classes is not located in classses.dex (class encryption)

Therefore, I can't use apk re-compile for debugging mode using apktool.

Is there another debugging way in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Encrypted files may restrict you debugging